# Ошибка при запуске бота на JS

Tags: javascript, discord, бот

Начал значит изучать JS, мне нужно написать бота, написал вроде код, следуя советам на видосе, но блин выдало стремную ошибку. Что значит хз, загуглил - выдало не то. Помогите плиз : (

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
let config = require('./config.json')
let token = config.token
let prefix = config.prefix

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Bot connected ${bot.user.username}`);
});

bot.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

  if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
    await interaction.reply('Pong!');
  }
});

bot.login(token);
```

Визуал код студио выдал ошибку:

```
PS C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\JSBot> node bot.js
C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\JSBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:548
      throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
      ^

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\JSBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:548:13)
    at new Client (C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\JSBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:76:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\JSBot\bot.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
}
PS C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\JSBot>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В новых версиях  discord.js начиная с ^13.0 вы должны явно обзначить client intents:

```
const bot = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
```

Comment: чёрт, совсем забыл, спасибо большое ))